# Casting Problems in Dotnetnuke Blog

Tags: asp.net, casting, blogs, dotnetnuke-module

i have installed blog module on my dotnetnuke site, now the problem is the default binding in the `viewbog.ascx` file is CodeBehind, by which i cannot execute the `.vb` code, so i have changed the CodeBehind to CodeFile, it throws the Error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.desktopmodules_blog_viewblog_ascx' to type 'DotNetNuke.Modules.Blog.ViewBlog'.
```

in `.vb` file, the default inherits is BlogModule, i thought that might be causing error, i changed it to `System.Web.UI.UserControl` still i am getting same problem can anyone tell what could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have changed the CodeBehind to CodeFile

I'm not exactly sure what you are going for here but it sounds like you are trying to change some functionality in the DNN Blog but I'm not sure you are going about it the proper way. You should download the source code of the DNN blog module [on Codeplex](http://dnnblog.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) get that setups and compiling so you CAN change the .vb file and have it working correctly.  What you are trying to do doesn't sound like the right direction.